# Keeping state in a constantly running python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python 2.7 script which is getting pretty unweildly.

The script runs constantly, in each loop it checks a few things, compares them to the previous run and makes some decisions.

The biggest problem I have is with the variables, I have half a dozen and I am limited in how I use them due to scope.

eg;

```
import time
import os

LOG_FILE = "/var/log/sc.log"
CHECK_FILE_TMP = "/tmp/myfile"
CHECK_FILE_USR = "/home/snoppy/testfile"
CHECK_FILE_TMP_TIME_INTERVAL = 20
CHECK_FILE_USR_TIME_INTERVAL = 30

def main():
    try:
         last_file_tmp_size = 0
         last_file_usr_size = 0
         last_file_tmp_mtime = 0
         last_file_usr_mtime = 0
         last_file_tmp_check_time = 0
         last_file_usr_check_time = 0
         tmp_file_changed = False
         usr_file_changed = False
         loop_start_time = 0


         print "Starting loop"

         while True:
            loop_start_time = time.time()
            if (time.time() - last_file_tmp_check_time > CHECK_FILE_TMP_TIME_INTERVAL):
                tmp_file_changed = checkFileChanged(CHECK_FILE_TMP, last_file_tmp_size, last_file_tmp_mtime)
                last_file_tmp_size = getFileSize(CHECK_FILE_TMP)
                last_file_tmp_mtime = getFileMTime(CHECK_FILE_TMP)
                if(tmp_file_changed):
                    logChange(CHECK_FILE_TMP, last_file_tmp_size, last_file_tmp_mtime)
                last_file_tmp_check_time = time.time()

            ....
            ....
            sleep(1)
    ...
```

So thats sort of what I am dealing with.
I have local variables, which I seem to be stuck with, I have to pass them around into functions - I don't want to call them global.

Ideally.... if I could get a main() function like

```
try:
   checkFile(CHECK_FILE_TMP)
   checkFile(CHECK_FILE_USR)
   sleep(0.1)
except:
...
```

as the main is so big! and I have to pass around the variables everywhere... it feels like the main function is so bloated!

Perhaps.... I might have to go for a class?

Comment: *I might have to go for a class?*: why don't you try that?

Comment: Have you considered running the script *periodically* (as opposed to continuously), and keeping state on one (or more) file(s)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Trying to keep to a single file...

Comment: @goncalopp - Need to check every 20 seconds ideally

Comment: @Wizzard: So? A Python class doesn't require a separate file, unlike Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the parts of your program that can be **abstracted** from their specific details and **reused** multiple times.
This is an art, don't expect it to be easy. You can find many books on Object oriented programming that explain the basics and give you some direction.

Here's just a quick example:

```
class FileChecker(object):

    def __init__(self, path, interval):
        self.path = path
        self.interval = interval
        self.last_size = None
        self.last_mtime = None
        self.last_check_time = None

    def hasChanged(self):
        ...

    def logChange(self):
        ...

class MultiFileChecker(object):

    DELAY = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = []
        self.loop_start_time = 0

    def addFile(self, f):
        self.files.append(f)

    def loop(self):
        try:
            print "Starting loop"
            while True:
                now = time.time()
                self.loop_start_time = now
                for f in self.files:
                    if now - f.last_check_time > f.interval:
                        if f.hasChanged():
                            f.logChange()
                ...
                sleep(self.DELAY)
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checker = MultiFileChecker()
    checker.add(FileChecker("/var/log/sc.log", 10))
    checker.add(FileChecker("/tmp/myfile", 20))
    checker.add(FileChecker("/home/snoppy/testfile", 30))
    checker.loop()
```